# How to keep window always on desktop

Tags: wpf

I have made a clock app, when I click `ShowDesktop` on taskbar it gets hidden. I want to show Window always on desktop, please, help me! 
I do not know to much English!

Answer (score 0):

When you click Show Desktop on the start menu, Windows asks all windows to minimize.
Hook into the StateChanged event and override this action with a default setting.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp7.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp7"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" 
    Topmost="True" StateChanged="MainWindow_OnStateChanged">
</Window>

private void MainWindow_OnStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var window = (Window) sender;

    if (window.WindowState == WindowState.Minimized)
        window.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
}
```

Comment: @ĐôEm If this solution answered your questions, please mark as accepted answer. For help, please reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

`<Window... TopMost="True">`

If you set TopMost propety to true, your app will be always on top. You can set it to false when you don't want to keep it on top.